# Java equals() ordering

Tags: java, string

If I try to do a `.equals()` on a null string in java, a null pointer exception will be thrown. I am wondering, if I am trying to compare if a string is equal to some constant string, can I do the following:

```
MY_CONSTANT_STRING.equals(aStringVariable)
```

I know it will work, but is this just really poor code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a standard Java idiom jokingly called a [Yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions/).

Personally I prefer to handle the null case explicitly, but the Yoda way is used a lot and any experienced Java programmer should be able to understand what is going on immediately. It's fine to use.

Comment: +1 cause I've just learnt Master Yoda's Conditions thanks to this answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307

Answer (score 6):

> is this just really poor code?

No, this is the way many people would code the statement to avoid NPE.

Answer (score 5):

What you've got is fine.  It's even possible to use a String literal.

```
if( "value".equals(variable) ) {
    ...
```

If you don't like that, you can always explicitly check for `null` and equality, and combine the two checks with `&&`.  The short circuiting of the operator will make sure you never get a NPE.

```
if( (variable != null) && variable.equals("value") ) {
    ...
```

Comment: The parentheses around variable!=null are optional should you wish to reduce the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the "CONSTANT.equals(possibleNull)" code without the null test only if it is a normal condition that the variable could be null - for instance because it just came out of a property map.

Similarly you can get away with not checking for null in instanceof-checks - like:

```
Food dinner = map.get("dinner");
if (dinner instanceof Soup) {
      ((Soup)blah).eat();
}  // We don't care if it is a Fish or null
```

But if you really did not expect null, you should explicitly check for that in a separate if-test, and handle it appropriately. It's generally better to catch such data errors early rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's usually done to avoid NPE. However, I usually prefer to do explicit check for null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the quality of your code, write a helper class that takes care of equality test:

```
public class ObjectHelper {
    public static boolean testEquality(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return true;
        if (o1 == null) return false;
        return o1.equals(o2);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if (ObjectHelper.testEquality(aStringVariable, My_CONSTANT_STRING))
```

Your so-called constant MIGHT stop being constant. It might be read from a configuration file some time in the future.

Comment: Java 7 has a builtin helper method [`java.util.Objects.equals(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) that does just this.

Comment: if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return true;
should just be: if (o1 == o2) return true;