# What is better way to compare Strings?

Tags: java, string

Which among the 2 is better way to compare String?

```
String str="Hello";

//case 1:
if(str.equals("Hello")){

//case 2:
if("Hello".equals(str))
```

Comment: consider if `str` can be null

Comment: The latter is a yoda condition. If `str` is null, the first will fail but the latter will not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418680/5647260 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9888508/5647260

Comment: Well, second answer to that post.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `case 2` whenever I need to compare with a constant string.

```
if("Hello".equals(str))
```

Above avoids `NullPointerException`.

**Update:-**

I don't think there are any performance issues because for CPU it will be same, the order doesn't matter.

But at few places, it eats up the readability.

```
(5==num)
```

In the above, you will be reading it as `5 is equal to num` and not `num is equal to 5`.

Comment: Isn't there any performance issue or something, I have always been confused on this question. Is using Yoda conditions have any downside?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh I don't think there will be any performance issues. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the latter.

```
"Hello".equals(str) //prevents NullPointerExceptions.
```

You can also read about Yoda Conditions!

Answer (score 1):

Consider this scenario:

```
String str = null;

//case 1:
if(str.equals("Hello")){

//case 2:
if("Hello".equals(str))
```

In the above code, case 1 is going to fail but case 2 will not. So the latter one is better.

However, if you're considering performance, then there's no difference between the two.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting if there is any performance issue. If there is no performance issue, Undoubtedly second approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is safer because it won't throw a NullPointerException if str is null